# What is the Steenrod algebra for finite fields?

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory, cohomology-operations

I understand that the Steenrod algebra for finite fields with $p$ elements ($p$ prime) is understood, but do we know what the Steenrod algebra is for all finite fields?

Namely, what is $H\mathbb F_{p^n}^* \left ( H \mathbb{F}_{p^n} \right )$ for $p$ prime?

Comment: I don't know enough algebraic  topology to answer for sure, but [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0903.4997.pdf) is a link to Larry Smith's _An Algebraic Introduction to the Steenrod Algebra_, which defines such an object for fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. I'm not sure how (or if) these relate nicely to the topological definition, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've looked into Smith's paper but unfortunately as Smith says in their closing comments I would like the "topological" Steenrod algebra instead of the algebra of reduced power operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you don't get any new topological classes.  Write $q = p^n$ and $\mathcal{A}^*$ for the mod $p$ Steenrod algebra; we also suppress the $H$ in the notation for Eilenberg-MacLane spectra.

We have $$\DeclareMathOperator{\Map}{Map} \Map(\mathbb{F}_q, \mathbb{F}_q) \simeq \Map_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathbb{F}_q, \Map(\mathbb{F}_p, \mathbb{F}_p) \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathbb{F}_q).$$  The "mod $q$ Steenrod algebra" is the homotopy groups of this mapping object, which we can compute using the universal coefficients theorem and the Kunneth theorem. Thus we deduce that $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{F}_q^* \mathbb{F}_q &\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathbb{F}_q, \mathcal{A}^* \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathbb{F}_q) \\ &\cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathbb{F}_q \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} \mathcal{A}^*. \end{align*}$$

One quick check this at least has the correct size is to note that $\mathbb{F}_q \simeq \mathbb{F}_p^{\oplus n}$ as groups (in fact as $\mathbb{F}_p$-modules) and therefore also as spectra, so $\mathbb{F}_q^* \mathbb{F}_q \cong (\mathbb{F}_p^{\oplus n})^* \mathbb{F}_p^{\oplus n}$, which is $n^2$ copies of $\mathbb{F}_p^* \mathbb{F}_p =: \mathcal{A}^*$.